# How do I set the subject of an Advanced PDF email template in NetSuite

Tags: email, pdf, netsuite

I've created an advanced PDF in NetSuite set it as the 'EMAIL TEMPLATE' in a custom transaction form. I can't use the normal email templates as the form is set to advanced and there is an advanced pdf 'PRINT TEMPLATE' specified already.

My question is: how do I set the subject of the e-mail?

There seems to be no option anywhere to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the subject of transaction emails using below steps -

1. Navigate to Setup > Customization > Transaction Forms.
2. Edit the preferred Sales Order form.
3. Go to Printing Fields tab > Header sub tab.
4. In the Company Name field, mark the Print/Email checkbox.
5. In the Label field, enter the subject that you want to use when emailing orders.
6. Hit Save.
   For example, if User enters "Test Company" in the Label field, the email subject would be: "Test Company: Sales Order # XXXXX".

For further details please refer SuiteAnswers - 34724,30117.

Comment: Ah I see where that comes from now. However, my client wants a dynamic subject to say something like "Thank you for ordering from ${transaction.location} store."

Comment: Ok at least I can change the text, so that's half the job. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This is an update to the steps above. Printing type needs to be changed before the printing fields can be seen.

1. Navigate to Setup > Customization > Transaction Forms.
2. Edit the preferred Sales Order form.
3. Change printing type to Basic.
4. Go to Printing Fields tab > Header sub tab.
5. In the Company Name field, mark the Print/Email checkbox.
6. In the Label field, enter the subject that you want to use when emailing orders.
7. Change printing type back to Advanced.
8. Hit Save.